# Problem publishing a .pbix file to PBI Workspace using the rest api and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-api, powerbi-rest-api

I am trying to publish a Power BI Report via a PowerShell script.
Has anyone had much experience with this as I can't quite get it to work using this method.

```
$clientId = "****"
$clientSecret = "****"
$tenantId = "****"
$apiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{Workspace}/imports?datasetDisplayName={DatadetName}"

$pbixFilePath = ".\BIDeploymentPlan.pbix"

$resourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"

$tokenBody = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    resource      = $resourceUrl
    scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token" `
    -Method POST -Body $tokenBody

$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
}

$body = @{
    filePath = $pbixFilePath
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1

$restMethodParams = @{
    Uri         = $apiUrl
    Method      = 'Post'
    Headers     = $headers
    Body        = $body
    ContentType = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-RestMethod @restMethodParams
```

I have used the following document to build this script:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/

Thank you for any help you can offer.

No issue with my access token as the following code works fine:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Method Delete -Headers $headers